# C# How to do loop variable for query (where)

Tags: c#, sql-server

Please help I can't understand about variable for query by when in SQL command. -> get value and do loop again and again (get and change) sorry I'm not good english

This code :

```
var ee = 0;
var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Values,date  FROM db_db where date ='" + ee ", connection);
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
var dt = 8;

for (int i = 0; i <= dt; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("A", starttime.AddMonths(i).ToString("MM", seCultureInfo) + "/" + starttime.AddMonths(i).ToString("yyyy", seCultureInfo));
    mm = "1";
}

while (reader.Read())
{
    var value = reader.GetDecimal(2);

    //   var column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    //   column.HeaderText = header.ToString();
    //   this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);
    if (dataGridView1.RowCount < 2)
    {
        this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
    }

    this.dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[columnIndex].Value = value;
    /* This --------------->*/ ee++;                     

    columnIndex++;
}
```

Look at "ee". I want to keep value "ee" and bring it back in query command by new "ee".

[image]

Last date of value was wrong it's correct at 07/2015

Comment: @Eliz, we don't understand what you need actually to help you, give some  more clarity about your question,

Comment: there are localized versions of stackoverflow (in other languages). use the one with your language, or get someone with better english to fix this question for you.

Comment: When you use parameters in this query (always an excellent improvement to prevent sql injection), then you can update the value of the parameter and execute the command again.

Comment: I have new sample picture.

Comment: Isn't `ee` supposed to be a `DateTime`? I think there is something wrong with the DB design.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly , you want to reuse the SQL but increasing the 'ee' variable .
It is impossible .
If your business logic is about query based on different date, You have to build the SQL command again and again .